# Convert my model part of MVC from array to dictionary

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary

let's assume that my model has the following:

```
import Foundation

class Model {


    var userName = [String]()
    var userAnswer = [String]()
    var userInfo = [String]()
    var name:String
    var answer:String

    init(){
        self.name = ""
        self.answer = ""

    }

    func addUserInfo(name:String, answer:String) -> Void {
        userName.append(name)
        userAnswer.append(answer)
    }

}
```

What would one do to transform this model to have userName, and userAnswer become one joined dictionary? where the function addUserInfo would still work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a funcion return a array or a new property  with only get methord,just like this

```
var userNamesAndUserAnswers:[[String:String]]
{
    get
    {
        var values:[[String:String]]=[]
        for index in 0..<userName.count
        {
            values.append(["name":userName[index],"answer":userAnswer[index]])
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a Dictionary that represents user names mapped to user answers like this:

```
class Model {
  var userInfo = [String:String]()

  func addUserInfo(name:String, answer:String) {
    userInfo[name] = answer
  }
}
```

There's no need to import Foundation since you're not using any Foundation objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `[String: String]`:

```
var dict: [String: String] {
    var result: [String: String] = [:]

    zip(userName, userAnswer).forEach { result[$0.0] = $0.1 }

    return result
}
```

Or if you want `[[String: String]]`:

```
var dict2: [[String: String]] { return zip(userName, userAnswer).map { [$0.0: $0.1] } }
```

Comment: This won't work, I would try the code in a compiler since there are multiple errors in it.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry to leave. Made some changes and forgot to apply it.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that!

Comment: Yea, extremely annoying when your wife keeps whining at you about the time and you just want to finish the finishing touch :p